# How to use opencv in Python3 to read file from file buffer

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv

I am trying to use [this](https://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_gui/py_image_display/py_image_display.html) library. In particular these 3 lines:

```
    image_stream = io.BytesIO(image_bytes)
    frame = cv2.imread(image_stream)
```

and I am having an exception:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/a/Pictures/pycharm-community-2018.3.2/helpers/pydev/pydevd.py", line 1741, in <module>
    main()
  File "/home/a/Pictures/pycharm-community-2018.3.2/helpers/pydev/pydevd.py", line 1735, in main
    globals = debugger.run(setup['file'], None, None, is_module)
  File "/home/a/Pictures/pycharm-community-2018.3.2/helpers/pydev/pydevd.py", line 1135, in run
    pydev_imports.execfile(file, globals, locals)  # execute the script
  File "/home/a/Pictures/pycharm-community-2018.3.2/helpers/pydev/_pydev_imps/_pydev_execfile.py", line 18, in execfile
    exec(compile(contents+"\n", file, 'exec'), glob, loc)
  File "/home/a/Documents/wiker/main.py", line 13, in <module>
    if __name__ == '__main__': main()
  File "/home/a/Documents/wiker/main.py", line 10, in main
    article['video'] = video.make_video_from_article(article)
  File "/home/a/Documents/wiker/video.py", line 15, in make_video_from_article
    frame = cv2.imread(image_stream)
TypeError: bad argument type for built-in operation
```

But it works on real files. what can be fixed here.

Comment: What do you get if you print out `print(type(image_stream))` ?

Comment: <class '_io.BytesIO'>

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46624449/load-bytesio-image-with-opencv

Comment: Read the docs. `imread` takes a filename as the first parameter, not a stream. It's meant to read from files only. If you want to decode data from memory, you need to use `imdecode`.

Comment: Are your `image_bytes` even encoded?

Comment: i get image data this way `image_content = get("https://" + image_url).content` with `from requests import get`

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Here a solution:

```
import io, requests, cv2, numpy as np

url = "https://images.pexels.com/photos/236047/pexels-photo-236047.jpeg"
img_stream = io.BytesIO(requests.get(url).content)
img = cv2.imdecode(np.frombuffer(img_stream.read(), np.uint8), 1)

cv2.imshow("img", img)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Comment: This is awesome thanks - what if I want to do the opposite? go from cv2 to io stream?

Comment: @Rami.K https://stackoverflow.com/a/64849668/9311137