# How to process images from telegram bot without saving to file

Tags: python, heroku, flask, computer-vision, telegram-bot

My telegram bot is designed to do image classification so I need to first read in the image from the user, for example, by using `cv2.imread(telegram_image.jpeg, 1)` before doing any processing and running my model on it. Is there a way to do this without having to download the image file from the telegram bot?

This is the code I have so far:

```
bot = telegram.Bot(token=TOKEN)
@app.route('/{}'.format(TOKEN), methods=['POST'])
def start():
    # retrieve the message in JSON and then transform it to Telegram object
    update = telegram.Update.de_json(request.get_json(force=True), bot)
    chat_id = update.message.chat.id
    msg_id = update.message.message_id
    imageId = update.message.photo[len(update.message.photo)-1].file_id
```

I am trying to deploy on Heroku (using Flask), but was having issues previously trying to download the files using `update.message.photo[-1].get_file().download()`. The code ran without errors but I couldn't find the image file anywhere.

Sorry I am quite new to this, would really appreciate any help or suggestions, thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suggest using [`python-telegram-bot`](https://github.com/python-telegram-bot/python-telegram-bot/wiki) for this, if you aren't already.  The wiki is great, and avoids the use of Flask.

You can avoid saving the file to disk, and store it in memory using `BytesIO`.  A function to handle a message might look like this:

```
from io import BytesIO

def photo(update: Update, context: CallbackContext):
    file = context.bot.get_file(update.message.photo[-1].file_id)
    f =  BytesIO(file.download_as_bytearray())

    # f is now a file object you can do something with

    result = somefunction(f)

    response = 'I procsseed that and the result was %s' % (result,)

    context.bot.send_message(chat_id=update.message.chat_id, text=response)
```

Then add the handler to the dispatcher.  Notice by using `Filters.photo` only messages which are photos will reach this handler:

```
photo_handler = MessageHandler(Filters.photo, photo)
dispatcher.add_handler(photo_handler)
```

This supports the latest version (v12) of the API.

You may also wish to have a look at a script I put together: [tg_client.py](https://github.com/vulcan25/image_processor/blob/master/tg/src/tg_client.py).  This is part of a larger repo which does image processing via the `Yolov3` library.  It also implements support for locking bot communication down to your own telegram user ID (see my [wiki page](https://github.com/vulcan25/image_processor/wiki/Telegram-Bot) for more info).

You could probably modify this for your own needs by swapping the `upload` function out for something that calls your own processing script.

---

**EDIT**:  I think I partially misread your question, so I'll answer this part:

> by using `cv2.imread(telegram_image.jpeg, 1)` before doing any processing and running my model on it. Is there a way to do this without having to download the image file from the telegram bot?

I've handled this in my code with thanks to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54162776/2052575) which suggests the use of `cv2.imdecode` in place of `cv2.imread`.

So `somefunction` above, could handle this like:

```
def somefunction(input_stream):
    image = cv2.imdecode(numpy.fromstring(input_stream, numpy.uint8), 1)

    # image is now what cv2.imread('filename.jpg',1) would have returned.

    # rest of your code.

    return 'the result of the processing'
```

This avoids writing the file to disk, as it's all handled in memory.

Answer (score 0):

This helped me:

```
def get_image(update, context):
    from io import BytesIO
    photo = update.message.photo[-1].get_file()
    # photo.download('img.jpg')
    # img = cv2.imread('img.jpg')
    img = cv2.imdecode(np.fromstring(BytesIO(photo.download_as_bytearray()).getvalue(), np.uint8), 1)
    ...
```