# compare bytestring and cv2.imread

Tags: python, opencv

I get bytestring from link with `requests.get(img_source).content`. And have variable `original = cv2.imread("original.png")` Are there ways to compare images without saving the first?

Comment: I already found answer on stackoverflow it was https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54160208/how-to-use-opencv-in-python3-to-read-file-from-file-buffer/54162776#54162776