# How to read image from buffer using OpenCV?

Tags: python, opencv, io

This is what I have so far... can't figure out how to read image from buffer vs file?

```py
import pyqrcode
import io
from cv2 import cv2

qr = pyqrcode.create("Hello")
buffer = io.BytesIO()
qr.svg(buffer)
# image = cv2.imread(path) // How to read image from buffer instead?
cv2.imshow('Image', image)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: I don't believe OpenCV can read vector graphics such as SVG, I think it only reads bitmapped graphics - I may be wrong. I suspect you'll either have to get `pyqrcode` to output a PNG (of which it is capable), or use `pyvips` or `wand` to read the SVG. If anyone knows better I am always happy to be corrected.

Comment: @MarkSetchell Interesting... thanks for helping out. Would you happen to know how to read `qr.png(buffer)` using `cv2`?

Comment: You'll need something like `cv2.imdecode(np.array(buffer.getcontents()), cv2.IMREAD_COLOR))` I'm not at a computer to test. You basically need to run `cv2.imdecode()` on something that looks like bytes or a Numpy array and starts with a PNG signature `\x89PNG`

Answer (score 1):

The following worked. Thanks Mark!

```py
import pyqrcode
import io
import numpy as np
from cv2 import cv2

buffer = io.BytesIO()
qr = pyqrcode.create("Hello")
qr.png(buffer)
buffer.seek(0)
array = np.asarray(bytearray(buffer.read()), dtype=np.uint8)
image = cv2.imdecode(array, cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)
cv2.imshow('Image', image)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: Well done! Thank you for sharing back with the SO community.

Comment: @MarkSetchell Hey Mark, depending on what I feed to `np.frombuffer`, I am getting `ValueError: buffer size must be a multiple of element size`. Would you happen to know what is going on?

Comment: @MarkSetchell Fixed the issue thanks to https://stackoverflow.com/a/47389660/4579271 and updated my answer.